# Does US preclearance in Toronto have a dedicated lane for diplomats?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, pre-clearance, yyz

In large US airports, the passport inspection hall includes a dedicated desk for diplomats, A visas, and G visas, sometimes including active duty military.

I did not see any such facility in Montreal when I was there four months ago.  Is there such a desk at the preclearance facility in Toronto?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively but I have heard such people are directed to the NEXUS queue at Toronto. If you're requesting port courtesy then the chief of protocol office should be able to tell you for sure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton isn't the nexus queue a kiosk queue?  How would that work for a G-4 visa holder, who can't use the kiosks?  Also, as far as I'm aware there is no port courtesy available for G-4 visas.

Comment: Yeah, that's one reason why I'm not sure about what I heard. As for port courtesy I'm reading [this document](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/170352.pdf) which indicates G-4 holders may be eligible if they hold one of the listed government functions. Though I only see one, maybe two? positions on the list that might apply to a G-4 visa holder.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see any, except incidentally as a family member of someone else who is "high ranking." I guess we'll try the nexus line. In Montreal we went to a kiosk as instructed and then had to wait around quite a while for an officer.  I'm trying to judge how early we should arrive for our flight (in Montreal we were transferring, so had no control over the timing).

Answer (score 1):

The airport staff member at the head of the Nexus line did not allow us to use it, though it later occurred to me that perhaps we should have asked about a "diplomatic visa" rather than a "G visa."

The immigration officer attempted to fingerprint the G visa holder (and stamped the expired passport that bears the valid visa rather than stamping the new passport that is actually valid), so I didn't think he was likely to know anything and didn't ask him.

I thought about asking the preclearance supervisor, who was standing in front of a desk behind the passport inspection desks, but by that point it seemed more important to get to the gate promptly, so we did not.

The answer seems therefore still to be indeterminate, but if the Nexus lane really is available for this purpose, it will probably require asking for a supervisor to be allowed through.

Comment: Obtaining a Nexus card is very easy if you're a US citizen or permanent resident and then you'll be able to use the Nexus lanes at all times. Very useful for non Canadian airports too.

Comment: @JonathanReez anyone with a G visa is, like everyone with a nonimmigrant visa, necessarily neither a US citizen nor permanent resident and is therefore ineligible to apply for Nexus.  In our case we do not travel to Canada frequently enough for Nexus to make sense even if we could both apply for it: at other airports we use the diplomat line.